# Unable to read certificate from KeyStore when running Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, certificate, keystore

For some reason a KeyStore I load in a Unit Test appears to be empty, and I have no idea why.

I have a keystore file with a certificate in it here: `src/test/resources/public-keystore-name`

So, running this command in a terminal:

```
../src/test/resources$ keytool -list -keystore public-keystore-name -storetype PKCS12
```

I get the following output:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

aliasname, May 22, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 4E:87:CF:EF:FC:E1:37:63:36:E0:26:0C:1E:B3:65:BB:48:3A:83:1A
```

In my unit test, I can load and initiate a KeyStore from this file alright, but I cannot fetch the certificate that I have stored in it. The certificate has alias "aliasname", and password "password".

```
   @Test
   public void testUtil() throws Exception {

     KeyStore publicKS = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

     File publicKeyStoreFile = FileUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/public-keystore-name");
     FileInputStream fisPublic = new FileInputStream(publicKeyStoreFile);

     publicKS.load(fisPublic, "password".toCharArray());

     Certificate cert = publicKS.getCertificate("aliasname");

     System.out.println("Cert is: " + cert);
   }
```

Will always print:
"Cert is: null"

Why is the KeyStore empty in this Unit Test? (looking for aliases with Keystore.aliases() will return an empty set).

Answer (score 1):

The KeyStore was created using BouncyCastle-stuff, so that needed to go into the setting up of this KeyStore:

```
...
    KeyStore publicKS = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
...
```

"BC" is the shorthand for BouncyCastle, and can be used after running:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

I guess the default KeyStore is probably some Java standard?